# How to parse json data in jquery and append to a table row

Tags: php, jquery, json

i have submitted my form data to database successfully. if the query runs then it will select that last row inserted and should return as json data and append to view table . I can not find how to parse that json data on success function of jquery
here is my code

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: form.attr("action"),
        data: $("#myForm input").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
        //alert("Branch Added Successfully");.
        if(data == 0){
            alert('Product Already Exists');
         }else{
             var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name="+ data.enq_id +"></td><td>" + data.category + "</td><td>" + data.brand + "</td><td>" + data.product_name + "</td><td><i class='fa fa-inr'></i> " + data.price + ".00 </td><td>" +
                         data.quantity + "</td><td><i class='fa fa-inr'></i> " + data.totalprice + " .00</td></tr>";
            $("table tbody").append(markup);
            var frm = document.getElementsByName('myForm')[0];
            // Submit the form
            frm.reset();  // Reset all form data
            return false;
               }
            }
     });
```

here is the action page i,e insert_inquiry_product.php

```
<?php
include('../../config.php');
extract($_POST);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //echo "success";
    $date=date('d-m-Y');
    $sql="select *  from enquiry_product where product_name='$productname' and enq_no='$enq_no'";
    $fire=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($fire) > 0){
        echo(0);
    }else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO `enquiry_product`(`enq_no`, `category_id`, `brand_id`, `product_name`, `price`, `quantity`, `total_price`) VALUES ('$enq_no','$category','$brand','$productname','$hid_mrp','$quantity','$hid_total')";
        //echo $query; die();
        $run_query=mysqli_query($link,$query);
        if($run_query){
            /**/
            //echo "<script>alert('Product Added successfully!');window.location='product.php'</script>";
            $selectquery="select `product_category`.`id` as `p_id` , `product_category`.`category_name` as `p_name`, `brand`.`id` as `b_id` ,`brand`.`brand_name` as `b_name` , `enquiry_product`.`id` as `en_id`, `product_name` ,`price`, `quantity`,`total_price` from `enquiry_product` inner join `brand` on `enquiry_product`.`brand_id` = `brand`.`id` left outer join `product_category` on `brand`.`cat_id` = `product_category`.`id` where `enquiry_product`.`enq_no` = '101' ORDER BY `enquiry_product`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1";
            //echo $selectquery; die();
            $selfire =mysqli_query($link,$selectquery);
            $res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($selfire);
            $en_id = $res['en_id'];
            $categ_name=$res['p_name'];
            $brand_name=$res['b_name'];
            $pro_name=$res['product_name'];
            $sprice=$res['price'];
            $quant=$res['quantity'];
            $t_price=$res['total_price'];

            echo json_encode(
            array("enq_id" => $en_id ,"category" => $categ_name, "brand" => $brand_name , "product_name" => $pro_name, "price" => $sprice , "quantity" => $quant , "totalprice" => $t_price));
        }
        else{
            echo "Error in query";
        }
        }
    }
else{ echo "button is not set"; }?>
```

Comment: use `var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data)` to convert the response to a json object inside success function. Then you can use like `jsonObj.enq_id`

Comment: the value of json is only printing on the browser and not returning from the action page

Comment: Sorry couldn't understand. Can you kindly explain?

Comment: when i run the program in the browser it is only printing that echo json_encode(array(values)) like this `{"enq_id":"11","category":"Fashion","brand":"Adidas","product_name":"Tshirt","price":"359\r\n","quantity":"2","totalprice":"718"}` the response is not returning to main page

Comment: When you submit the form are you redirected to another page where the values are printed?

Comment: yes. My form action page is insert_inquiry_product.php

Comment: If you want to use ajax you need to remove the action from the form and make it like `<form  onsubmit="return false;">` then in onclick listener of your submit button use the ajax function you've written

Comment: This would stop the form from redirecting and use the ajax call to fetch and display data. If you add an action page the user would be redirected to that page like you are and by returning false in onsubmit you stop the values from submitting automatically and do this yourself using ajax in the background

Comment: You can also do something like ` $(document).ready(function() {
    // process the form
    $('form').submit(function(event) {
        //make ajax call
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});`

Comment: yeah. Thank you bro